# .htaccess mod_rewrite catch all stuck in loop

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file and I am trying to rewrite the following:

**myserver.com/path1/path2/** -> **myserver.com/?customer=path1&portal=path2**

then a catch all for anything else that is not a file, directory or symbolic link to go to the root of the server e.g. myserver.com/

I would have thought that myserver.com/?customer=path1&portal=path2 would be detected as a file i.e. index.php which is the root of the server or is the query string throwing it off?

Can anyone tell me why this is looping infinitely and how to fix?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /?customer=$1&portal=$2 [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301]
```

**EDIT**:

I have just tried the following

```
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/?customer=$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301]
```

Now

```
http://myserver.com/path1/
```

Redirects to:

```
https://myserver.com/?customer=path1
```

However

```
https://myserver.com/path1/
```

Redirects to:

```
http://myserver.com/
```

So why does https cause the rule not to match?

Comment: Can you make sure you are not already redirected with `RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]` matching `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443`?

Comment: @antoni not quite sure what you mean. Those should catch anything non-https and make it https and then go through the rules again.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you are trying with the port #443, you will pass the first condition.

Then the following RewriteCond seems to not do exactly what you want, you can try this instead: `RewriteRule ([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /?customer=$1&portal=$2 [L,R]`.
So basically it's just removing the beginning of string match `^`.

You can try it on a very good tool here: http://htaccess.mwl.be/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !443
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /?customer=$1&portal=$2 [L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301]
```

**[EDIT]**

Try isolating your problem into a simple example:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /?customer=$1&portal=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301]
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
print_r($_SERVER);
```

now in browser: `view-source:http://localhost/path1/path3/` will output:

```
Array
(
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [HTTP_HOST] => localhost
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
    [SERVER_NAME] => localhost
    [SERVER_ADDR] => ::1
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => ::1
    ....
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 57976
    [REDIRECT_URL] => /path1/path3/
    [REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING] => customer=path1&portal=path3
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => customer=path1&portal=path3
    [REQUEST_URI] => /path1/path3/
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /index.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1483066179.854
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1483066179
)
```

> `[QUERY_STRING] => customer=path1&portal=path3`

You shouldn't use redirect as the query string is already what you want.
In this example the redirect doesn't loop forever.

Comment: Why do you add `R` flag after rewriting, is it purposely? you should keep same url and translate it through your rule but not redirect, I think this is causing the loop

Comment: Because I want it to hit the server as myserver.com/?customer=path1&portal=path2 but even if I use this url directly it loops infinitely. so the last rule must be picking it up but I am not sure why as the RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f rule should stop it progressing as it would hit my index.php or do I need to specify index.php?

Answer (score 0):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
## If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ ?customer=$1&portal=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule . / [L,R=301]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.